# Add breakpoint to div on mobile phone

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I just discovered / started to learn media queries. Im having a rather hard time at getting used to it. Im looking for an example / some help with the following.

**CSS**

```
.col-left{
    height:300px;
    background:red; 
}

.col-right{
    height:300px;
    background:yellow;      
}
.icon-container{
    padding:20px 20px;
    background-color:blue;
    height:300px;
}
.heading-container{
    padding:20px 20px;
    background-color:black;
    height:300px;   
     font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #141415;
    font-weight: 900;
    color:white;
}
```

**This is my HTML with Bootstrap**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-left">
            <div class="row item-container">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 icon-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-usd fa-3x"></i>
                </div><!--/icon-container -->
                <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 heading-container">
                    <p>Loren Ipsum This is some random text</p>
                </div><!--/heading-container -->
            </div><!--/.row item-container -->
        </div><!--/col6 -->

        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-right">
        </div><!--/col6 -->
    </div><!--/row -->    
</div><!--/container -->
```

**OUTPUT DESKTOP**

The desktop output is fine and displaying as I want it to display.

[image]

**Mobile Output**

The problem comes in when viewing the above code on a mobile device. When viewed on mobile device I get the following output:

[image]

The above output, is WRONG as I want the viewport to break after the black heading div. I would like to get a mobile output like the following image below:

**Desired Output**

[image]

If anyone could point me in the right direction here it would be greatly appreciated. I tried to follow the following [tutorial via w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), without success.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to read http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. Especially how it works on different screen sizes. (the part of the classes that defines the screensixze it should apply to: xs, sm, md, lg )

Comment: @RMo THANK YOU! So you if I understand this correctly - bootstrap eliminates the need for media queries, providing it is used correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using bootstrap: so inbuilt class will help you in that:

Check this out:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-left">
        <div class="row item-container">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 icon-container">
                <i class="fa fa-usd fa-3x"></i>
            </div><!--/icon-container -->
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 heading-container">
                <p>Loren Ipsum This is some random text</p>
            </div><!--/heading-container -->
        </div><!--/.row item-container -->
    </div><!--/col6 -->

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-right">
    </div><!--/col6 -->
</div><!--/row -->
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30212/)

Comment: Thank you Afsar! So you are saying by correctly using bootstrap I do not need to write media queries...?

Comment: true, But for few tweaks you can write.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `col-xs-*` of `.col-left` and `.col-right` to `col-xs-12`